# How to get width and height of particular object using sceneform SDK and ARCore like Google Measure app?

Tags: android, kotlin, arcore, sceneform

I want to get width and height of a live object such as water bottle, a notebook, keyboard, etc.. so my question is how to get width and height of a live object using ARCore and Sceneform SDK android.

Example:
Like Google measure app.

Comment: You wanna get the size of a object using your screen as parameter?

Comment: I have created an app where I am scaling the object to detect the height. Here is my github link: https://github.com/shubh261096/measurementapp

Answer (score 0):

ARCore's coordinate system is using meters so you have to create two anchors and calculate the distance between them. Just use the world position of the Anchors, subtract them and the length of the resulting vector.

Comment: This will be for the distance between two anchors placed on the plane but what about the height measurement? How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method by which you can get the distance between two anchors:

```
float getMetersBetweenAnchors(Anchor anchor1, Anchor anchor2) {
    float[] distance_vector = anchor1.getPose().inverse()
            .compose(anchor2.getPose()).getTranslation();
    float totalDistanceSquared = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        totalDistanceSquared += distance_vector[i] * distance_vector[i];
    return (float) Math.sqrt(totalDistanceSquared);
}
```